# Deleting MySQL records from multiple tables doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql, delete-row, multiple-tables

Hi Guys I'm trying to delete multiple records from three tables.
However it doesn't work as expected.

My Query:

```
DELETE FROM offer, offer_products, offer_product_addons 
USING offer, offer_products, offer_product_addons  
WHERE offer.offer_number IS NULL
AND offer_products.offer_id = offer.id 
AND offer_product_addons.offer_products_id = offer_products.id;
```

My guess is that it't doesn't delete a record when there is no record found in one of the other tables. How can I make this work, I already tried with join's but that deletes only the content from the main table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use the `CASCADE` function on multiple operations namely delete or Update.

`CASCADE` - If ON `UPDATE CASCADE` or `ON UPDATE SET NULL` recurses to update the same table it has previously updated during the cascade, it acts like `RESTRICT`. This means that you cannot use self-referential ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON `UPDATE SET NULL` operations. This is to prevent infinite loops resulting from cascaded updates. A self-referential `ON DELETE SET NULL`, on the other hand, is possible, as is a self-referential `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Cascading operations may not be nested more than 15 levels deep.

Sometimes, it is useful to know which table is affected by the `MySQL ON DELETE CASCADE`  referential action when you delete data from the parent table. You can query this data from the referential_constraints in the information_schema  database as follows:

**Code:**

```
USE information_schema;
SELECT table_name
FROM referential_constraints
WHERE constraint_schema = 'database_name' AND
      referenced_table_name = 'parent_table' AND
      delete_rule = 'CASCADE'
```

**Example:**

For example, to find tables that associated with the **buildings** table with the `CASCADE  delete rule`  in the **classicmodels** database, you use the following query:

```
USE information_schema;

SELECT table_name
FROM referential_constraints
WHERE constraint_schema = 'classicmodels' AND
      referenced_table_name = 'buildings' AND
      delete_rule = 'CASCADE'
```

Another Alternative Example for `DELETE CASCADE`:

If your `cascading deletes` nuke a product because it was a member of a category that was killed, then you've set up your foreign keys improperly. Given your example tables, you should have the following table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE category (
    id int unsigned not null primary key,
    name VARCHAR(255) default null
)Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE product (
    id int unsigned not null primary key,
    name VARCHAR(255) default null
)Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE category_product (
    category_id int unsigned not null,
    product_id int unsigned not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (category_id, product_id),
    KEY pkey (product_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category (id)
       ON DELETE CASCADE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product (id)
       ON DELETE CASCADE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE
)Engine=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Ok, but I now don't have the option to alter the table to use foreign keys with the option cascade. Is there no other simple way ? To use this once for a cleanup?

Comment: @lason Your code will fail and you have no condition to join the table if the join table does not have value in it. For that purpose alone you need to cascade and this will be very useful for you to implement bulk delete or bulk update as  you need.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation @Naresh , I'm going to change the tables then when I have the opportunity .